# sub of subset given a list

Tags: python, recursion

If you are given the following list: `a = [1, 2, 3, 2, 1]`.
which adds up to 9.
I'm looking for all possible combinations less than 5 (this can be configured) that adds up to 9. For example:

```
[5 4] is valid
[3 3 3] is valid 
[4 3 2] is valid
```

and so on `[1, 2, 3, 2, 1]` is also valid.
Also, it can't be bigger than the size of the given list (a) so:
`[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]` is not valid.

I have tried (according to some comments I saw):

```
def subset_sum(numbers, target, partial=[], partial_sum=0):
    if partial_sum == target:
        yield partial
    if partial_sum >= target:
        return
    for i, n in enumerate(numbers):
        remaining = numbers[i + 1:]
        yield from subset_sum(remaining, target, partial + [n], partial_sum + n)
```

but I'd like to generate a list such as `[5, 4]` not only using a given list.

Comment: Its customary to make at least some kind of attempt at the problem yourself.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried. You can [edit] it into your question. If possible, include a [mcve]. This helps us understand your question better, and improves your chance of getting a useful answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think some version of this will get the jobs done

```
import itertools
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
for p in itertools.product(x, repeat=3):
    if(sum(p)==9):
        print(p)
```